# How to prevent active storage updating model when validation fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activestorage

My User model `has_one_attached :avatar`

Here I have some validation methods

```
  validate :validate_avatar_presence
  validate :validate_avatar_format
  validate :validate_avatar_size

  private

  def validate_avatar_presence
    errors.add(:avatar, 'should exist') unless self.avatar.attached?
  end

  def validate_avatar_size
    if self.avatar.attached?
      purge_avatar('File is too big') if self.avatar.blob.byte_size > 2000000
    end
  end

  def validate_avatar_format
    if self.avatar.attached?
      purge_avatar('Wrong format') unless self.avatar.blob.content_type.starts_with?('image/')
    end
  end

  def purge_avatar(msg)
    errors.add(:avatar, msg)
    avatar.purge_later
  end
```

Regardless of what I'm uploading, user avatar gets updated. If validations fail, avatar becomes nil, otherwise I get what I've uploaded. I tried to validate via before_update callback. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active Storage doesn’t currently support validations, but full support is coming in Rails 6.0. Until 6.0 is released, use Rails master, which [avoids storing files when validations fail](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33303).

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to [Active Storage Validations gem](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like ActiveStorage doesn't support validations right now. According to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31656.

Comment: That's why I've created custom validation methods. I hope there is a way to validate Active Storage. Otherwise, why did they release it?

Comment: Why they released it is it's still useful enough to some people without validations, and they can add validations later. It would probably be smart of them to log a warning or raise an exception when "validate" is called as your experience implies it's ignored.